# extract text from canvas panel which has been encoded in base64

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, base64

I have geotagged an image by using html canvas and using context.filltext to store longitude and latitude and context.drawimage to store the image. I have then used the todataURL() function to encode the canvas in base64 which I have saved to my database. I have then loaded this data from my database, is there a way to decode the data and extract the longitude and latitude in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you have is a simple image file as any other image file. Canvas does not separate the graphics you draw to it incl. text (which becomes rasterized).

You have to either:

- Supply the data as meta data to your server
- Run [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) on you image is this meta data is not an option (not related to canvas or html5 per-se).
- Send the original image to server and extract EXIF data there as well as make a burn-in.

You can for example create an object which contains your data-uri from toDataURL() and the long/lat data:

```
var geoImage = {
    image: canvas.toDataURL(),
    longitude: "xxxx",
    latitude: "yyyy"
}
```

Then encode it as JSON and send that to server:

```
var serverString = JSON.stringify(geoImage);
```

OCR as the other option is something I would only recommend if you don't have access to the original long/lat data. With some experience in the field I know you are in for quite a few challenges however and its not stable. A very good OCR module cost a lot of money and the cheaper ones will give you many errors. It also depends on how you draw the text on the image if the background is clear, the typeface is easy to analyze and so forth.

The obvious third option is perhaps better for quality reasons. When you draw your image onto canvas and then extract it you will loose quality. As most cameras store images only as either JPEG or RAW you will only have a single option with canvas, JPEG, which means it needs to be re-compressed with "lossy" compression. You can of course extract as PNG but that will increase the file size in most cases.

You can extract the EXIF data at server side as well. You can then store the original image together with a burn-in version.

Answer (score 2):

Not without using an optical character recognition software.

The moment you draw text to a canvas, it stops being text and starts to be a collection of pixels arranged in shapes a human observer would identify as characters.

Explaining how to implement an algorithm for optical character recognition would go much to far for the scope of this answer. I would recommend you to:

- Find a optical character recognition software which can be used from the command line
- Dump all the images in your database to image files
- Write a script which

  - Runs the OCR software for each image
  - See if it recognize text looking like geo coordinates (be aware of false-positives)
  - Update the entry in the database with the coordinates you found.

I just hope you have the text on plain background and at a fixed location in the images, otherwise the OCR software will have problems finding and identifying it.